# Change tint color UIAlertController iOS9

Tags: objective-c, ios9, uialertcontroller, tint

I am not sure that anyone has encountered such kind of a behavior or not but iOS9 is making my UIAlertController tint to inherit from the main window. Is there any specific way something like UIAppearance that can help and resolve the issue.

```
[[UICollectionViewCell appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
```

Comment: whatever the content that is behind the alert view, it will be shown on alert view, it is the tansparency of the alert that gives you the impression of tint color!!!

Comment: You can change the tint,backgroundColor,alpha properties for alertcontroller . What else do you need

Comment: @Mr.T I do understand that but there is no way I have found yet to override tint color as of now in iOS9. And also this behavior is for UIAlertController only

Comment: It appears to be a regression in ios 9 - https://openradar.appspot.com/22209332 - i had tintColor working perfectly in iOS8

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the `UIWindow` color in the AppDelegate like

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptionslaunchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    window?.tintColor = .redColor()
}
```

At least this worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Due to a known bug introduced in iOS 9 (https://openradar.appspot.com/22209332), the tintColor is overridden by the application window's tintColor.

See my full answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37737212/1781087