# How to change tint color of UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

Can I change colors of the `UIAlertController` ? A standard color is a blue color. And it's much close to the standard iOS apps. If it's customizable? How can I change colors of this? For example a button color.

Thanks!

Comment: Has a working method come up yet? All below answers are affected by the same bug.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could just change the `tintColor` of the underlying view, however, due to a known bug introduced in iOS 9 (https://openradar.appspot.com/22209332), the tintColor is overridden by the application window's `tintColor`.

You can either:

1. Change the app `tintColor` in the AppDelegate.

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
       self.window.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
       return true
   }
   ```
2. Reapply the color in the completion block.

   ```
   self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in
       alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
   })
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Works quite nice.

Comment: alertController.view.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; Works just fine for me

Answer (score 13):

In Swift, you could do something like this:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: As @guidev said, there's a bug that prevents alert controllers from honoring the `tintColor` that you set on them.

Comment: Looks like that bug has possibly been fixed. I just tested in Xcode 9.2 (9C40b) - iOS 11 and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: @MarkMoeykens I see the bug in iOS 12.

Comment: @MarkMoeykens, setting the tint color works for me, but only changes the action text colors, not the title color.  If you want to change the title color, you'll need to make a NSMutableAttributedString and then set the attributedTitle of the alert controller.  And yeah, good to see you, Mark - even if I am five years late.

Answer (score 5):

In **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9.2**

```
let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CONFIRM", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
                //my logic
            }))

alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .default, handler: nil))


alertView.view.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 45.0/255.0, green: 187.0/255.0, blue: 135.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Add one line in your UIAllertController :

```
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change the tintColor of the underlying view.

```
[alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
```

Comment: This is actually doable

Answer (score 1):

To change the tint color for all Alerts in Swift:

```
 extension UIAlertController{
    open override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
       self.view.tintColor = //color
    }
 }
```